# Mongoose relationship [one-to-many] best practice

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, best-in-place

I’m new  to mongoose and I have the following question.

What’s the best practice when creating a one-to-many relationship? for example lets say I have a persons schema as follow.

```
const personSchema = new Schema({
  fname: String,
  lName: String,
  email: String,
  dob: Date,
  address: {
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipCode: String,
  },
});
```

Then I have another weight schema where I have a person field referencing to the person’s object id.

```
const weight = new Schema({
  person: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  date: Date,
  weight: Number,
  unit: { type: String, enum: ['kg', 'lb'] },
});
```

My question is: Should I also add a property field to the person’s schema with an array of the weight’s object ids?

```
const personSchema = new Schema({
  fname: String,
  lName: String,
  weights: [
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: ‘Weight’
  ],
  email: String,
  dob: Date,
  address: {
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipCode: String,
  },
});
```

If I don’t add the weight's array, how can I populate or bring the Person’s weight when doing a Persons.find() query?

And in case I do need to add it. When creating a new person can I also create a new weight and add it to the weigh’s array within the same Persons.Create method?

Any suggestions and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: To decide whether to [embed or use reference](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/embedded-mongodb), it's best to think about the query patterns and use cases. Then update the schema accordingly.